# Maintaining the same Session in Child Window

Tags: php, session, sessionid

When a user arrives at my site, a session is started for them. There is a point where a **child window** is spawned using **JavaScript** on my sites home page.

This child window goes to Twitter site to authenticate the user and it gets **redirected** back to a script on my site which stores some variables in a SESSION.

I have found out that the PHP script in the child window isn't aware of the session and session_id that is set already and it therefore starts a new session which means the parent window (index.php) can not access those session variables.

I am **baffled**. What can I do?

### Update

Here is my code, but its not my code that is the problem, its the **implementation** that I am having trouble with.

**index.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

**oauth.php** //child window

```
<?php session_start();

$_SESSION['screen_name'] =  $twitterInfo->screen_name;

$_SESSION['profile_image_url'] = $twitterInfo->profile_image_url;

?>
```

When child window closes and I use AJAX to check a screen_name like so, it returns a no match as the child window oauth.php is using a **different session** (id).

```
<?php session_start();

    sleep(1);

    if(isset($_SESSION['screen_name'])){

        echo 'done';
        exit;

    }else{

        echo session_id().$_SESSION['screen_name'];
        exit;

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the same domain, then PHP should be aware of the session since all cookies are sent back to the domain that set them according to the HTTP specs.

Note that www.domain.com is a different domain then domain.com.
Cookies can also be set for a path on a domain, so make sure the path is the same.
Cookies can also be set for multiple sub domains using *.

If you post the relevant PHP code you have, it will help.

Comment: Thats what I didn't know! www.domain.com is a different domain then domain.com! Is there a way to make the same?? Do I edit my PHP.ini file?

Comment: www.domain.com is a subdomain of domain.com like any other (sub.domain.com...,forum.domain.com)
You can use ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.yourdomain.com') to make the php session cookie visible through all your subdomains.

Comment: You can instruct PHP to set the cookie to a specific domain, or include child domains with: session_set_cookie_params()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Note that is usually isn't good practice to set cookies to all sudomains. Some large profile sites have been subject of XSS attacks because of this. Yahoo and Hotmail in the past. It doesn't create an XSS vulnerability, but it makes it hard prevent it since any vulnerability infects all domains the cookie is set to.

Comment: To save you the headache of messing with your session handler, just make sure the domain twitter redirects to is the same as the parent window.

When writing AJAX apps, I usually use window.location.host property to get the domain in JS so that I'm sure the XMLHttpRequest is made to the same domain. You could use that to redirect your child window to the correct domain, or make the parent window open in the correct domain. 

You can also configure your server to redirect URLs to either www.domain.com or domain.com. This has the added benefit of SEO (theorectically).